# Why chain icon right side of the object showing up? How should I disable this?

Tags: objects

I'm worked on my project in Blender 2.79. Then I decided to transfer this to Blender 2.8

I appended successfully after I append.
I cannot move, add a modifier or edit materials.

How should I rid this thing and how is this works?
( I DON'T USE LINK BUTTON )

This is the picture (If you don't understand what I'm trying to say)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you linked instead of appending

Comment: I used the append button. And nothing is working

Comment: Consider uploading your file to Blend Exchange so we can take a look at it. If you cannot, try making a local version of the objects with Object > Relations > Make Local